# Random position on div creation

Tags: jquery, html, css, random

Currently I'm working on some layout with markers. These markers need to be placed randomly on my window and afterwards they need to be animated.  I'm currently creating 50 divs and they are getting placed randomly already. Except for the fact that all 50 are getting placed on the same random spot.

So I'm hoping if someone can point out on how to place all 50 divs on different random locations so not all on the same spot. I think I'm close but not sure what to do next.

Here is my code so far:
http://jsbin.com/cipewozali/edit?html,css,js,output

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are only generating one random number.  Move your randomX and randomY variable instantiations inside your serStartpnt function.

```
function setStartpnt(){
  var randomX = Math.floor(window.innerWidth * Math.random());
  var randomY = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * Math.random());
  marker.css({
    "transform":"translate("+randomX+"px, "+randomY+"px)"
  });
}
```

This way you will be generating a new random number every time you call this function.

Comment: Thanks did the trick. 4 Minutes untill I can mark this answer as right. Such an easy solution haha. I totally overlooked it. Thanks again!

Comment: An easy mistake to make.  I'm glad I could help!